# How to do a soft restart within Python 3 without exiting Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, cross-platform, restart

I am developing a Python 3 script to do what I have previously accomplished with Windows Batch and/or GNU/Linux shell scripts. The primary reason being that my organization uses both Windows and GNU/Linux, and we want a single script that will be operable on both platforms (easier to maintain, in theory).

My shell script will be simplified to

```
python name-of-python-script.py
```

I believe my present task will be simplified if I can do a soft restart from within a single Python session. (My platform-dependent script calls a sequence of independent Python instances, each of which has its own imports, object creation, etc. Not keeping the Python sessions independent could result in name conflicts.)

One solution for the Python script is:

```
# Beginning of Python Script
DIR = set(dir()).union({'DIR'}) # Remember what's in start-up scope
# Create a bunch of objects, do a bunch of function calls, etc. (#1)
exec('del ' + ', '.join(filter(lambda s: s not in DIR, dir()))) # Soft restart (#2)
# Alternate between #1 and #2
```

My present solution is:

```
restore = \
'''
for name in dir():
    part = name.partition('__')
    if name in ('restore', 'name', 'part'):
        pass # name is being used in-loop: don't delete
    elif part[0]: # name does not begin with '__'
        exec('del ' + name)
    elif part[1] == '__': # name begins with '__'
        part = ''.join(reversed(part[2])).partition('__')
        if part[0]: # name does not end with '__'
            exec('del ' + name)
    else:
        pass

del name, part
'''
# usage: exec(restore)
```

What is a more elegant solution? Specifically, for the first solution, I am interested in avoiding having to copy #2 verbatim every time I want to do the soft restart. Both solutions require `exec`, which would be nice to avoid.

I acknowledge feedback thus far (2018-12-08); still working on a minimal example.

Comment: just do a system call to python for each script, that will keep sessions independent.

Comment: @E.Serra Could you provide a code snippet?

Comment: The problem you’re asking about doesn’t exist unless you’re already doing something else weird. Modules have their own independent globals, so unless you’re explicitly monkeypatching another module (or builtins), or running these modules by manually loading them and execing them and passing the same dict to each, etc., they won’t have any name conflicts.

Comment: If you really need to do something like this, you can manipulate `globals()` instead of building statements to `exec`, and it’s not _as_ bad. But you probably don’t need this: either you don’t have a problem, or you’re working around a problem at a low level that could be trivially solved at a higher level, or there’s something weird that you just shouldn’t be doing. If you can show us an [mcve] with one-liner scripts and the driver script you write to run them all, we can probably show how to make that work.